# How to Replace special characters in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am starting to program in batch and I have this problem. If I enter the variable by argument, it does not change the accented characters or character ñ, but if I declare the variable directly in the program, it does.

```
@echo off 

set variable=%1
set variable=%variable:á=a%
set variable=%variable:é=e%
set variable=%variable:i=a%
set variable=%variable:ñ=n%
echo %variable%

set var=Holáéñ
set var=%var:á=a%
set var=%var:é=e%
set var=%var:ñ=n%
echo %var% 

C:\Users\bruno\OneDrive\Escritorio\powershell>prova holáéñi
holáéña
Holaen
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: You have to write the non [ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com/) characters using the [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) which is displayed on running in a command prompt window with your user account `chcp` like the OEM code page [850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) and not using the code page defined for Windows GUI applications as default for single byte per character encoded text files like [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). Or the batch file contains at top after `@echo off` a line like `%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com 1252 >nul`.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to  ***Mofi's comment*** :

> You have to write the non ASCII characters using the code page which
> is displayed on running in a command prompt window with your user
> account chcp like the OEM code page 850 and not using the code page
> defined for Windows GUI applications as default for single byte per
> character encoded text files like Windows-1252. Or the batch file
> contains at top after @echo off a line like
> %SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com 1252 >nul

---

You can write your batch like that :

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enableExtensions enableDelayedExpansion
set "cp="
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:." %%a in ('chcp') do set "cp=%%~a"
if not defined cp set "cp=850"
>nul chcp 1256 
set var=Holáéñ
set var=!var:á=a!
set var=!var:é=e!
set var=!var:ñ=n!
echo !var! 
>nul chcp %cp%
endlocal
pause & exit
```